# Run jar file as Daemon on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jar, daemon

I want to install a bot to my Teamspeak3 and run this bot as a daemon on startup. I wrote my own script and copied it to init.d and then added it with `update-rc.d` to defaults.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# JTS3ServerBot Script
#
USER="ts"
NAME="jts3"
DIR="/home/ts/jts3/"
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting ${NAME} ..."
        if [ ! -f $DIR/pid ]; then
            sudo -u $USER -c nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar $DIR 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
            echo $! > $DIR/pid
            echo "${NAME} started ..."
        else
            echo "${NAME} is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $DIR/pid ]; then
            PID=$(cat $DIR/pid);
            echo "Stopping ${NAME} ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "${NAME} stopped ..."
            rm $DIR/pid
        else
            echo "${NAME} is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $DIR/pid ]; then
            PID=$(cat $DIR/pid);
            echo "Stopping ${NAME} ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "${NAME} stopped ...";
            rm $DIR/pid

            echo "Starting ${NAME} ..."
            sudo -u $USER -c nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar $DIR 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
            echo $! > $DIR/pid
            echo "${NAME} started ..."
        else
            echo "${NAME} is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

A pid file in generated, but if i try to kill the process with this pid i get an error that the process does not exist. If i use `top` there is no process with the pid listed.

```
root@vps-1023645-8462:~# service jts3 start
Starting jts3 ...
jts3 started ...
root@vps-1023645-8462:~# cat /home/ts/jts3/pid 
10206
root@vps-1023645-8462:~# kill 10206
bash: kill: (10206) - No such process

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 1762 ts        20   0 1881m  14m 3408 S    0  1.4 215:47.28 ts3server_linux    
32356 ts        20   0  164m 1576 1336 S    0  0.2   0:09.85 tsdnsserver_lin
```

Comment: You are capturing the PID of `sudo`, not `java`... `sudo` probably exits after `nohup` exits after it runs your `java` command.

Comment: @twalberg That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Also, in order to avoid the capturing the sudo PID, you should use `ps -ef | grep JTS3ServerMod.jar | awk '{print $2}'`. That should give you  the PID of the running process.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Wasn't sure I wanted to make that an answer because it doesn't really solve the problem, it just points out where the problem is... A proper solution would probably require knowledge of what distro is in use, and whether things like `start-stop-daemon` or other similar scripts/facilities are available...

Comment: @twalberg That is not the cause - sudo does not fork by default (it just exec's and there is only one pid). The issue in this case is a spurious argument flag as I've detailed in my answer.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It seems to me that the question indicates that the daemon starts successfully, but has a different PID than what is captured by the script. This would tend to indicate that either `sudo` or `nohup` forked. You may be right about `sudo`, but that would just indicate that `nohup` is the culprit (which would be `/usr/bin/nohup` in this case, instead of a shell builtin version)...

Comment: The question shows no evidence that the daemon starts successfully. `nohup` doesn't fork either, it just exec's. You don't have to take my word for it, the source to both is pretty small and easy to read (and it's easy to test).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found another solution for my problem. I use **upstart** (works only with Ubuntu) to run my jar-File as a daemon. Upstart manages the PIDs. Just add `myservice.conf` to `/etc/init` (not `/etc/inid.d`) and the daemon will be started on boot and you can mangage it as a service. You do not have to make the file runnable or anything else

You can manage the service as normal for example

```
service myservice restart
service myservice status
...
```

My Config-File:

```
description "myservice"
author "your name"

start on runlevel [3]
stop on shutdown

expect fork

script   
    cd /home/username/
    sudo -u username java -jar /home/username/myservice/myservice.jar >/home/username/myservice.log 2>&1
    emit myservice_running
end script
```

This solution is really easy and works well on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line:

```
sudo -u $USER -c nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar $DIR 2>>/dev/null >>/dev/null&
```

You appear to be mixing the syntaxes of `sudo` and `su`. Before version 1.8, `sudo` had no `-c` option - you just give it the command to run after any other options. In 1.8 there is a `-c` option but it's not for specifying the command (it's for limiting resource usage to that of a given login class). `sudo` is printing an error message about this invalid syntax, but you're not seeing it because you're redirecting all the output to `/dev/null`.

Simply remove the `-c` to form a valid command:

```
sudo -u $USER nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar $DIR 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
```

Also, you can simplify the command a little by using the `2>&1` syntax to send `stderr` to the same handle as `stdout`, and there is no need for append mode when writing to `/dev/null`:

```
sudo -u $USER nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar $DIR >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: i changed my script but the process still does not start

Comment: Try running without the redirects and see if the revised command prints and error messages.

Comment: `sudo -u $USER nohup java -jar $DIR/JTS3ServerMod.jar` did you mean this my saying without redirects? because there happens nothing